# How to enable line number in kendo editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

How to add line number to kendo ui editor. I dont see any setting to enable line number 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/overview

Answer (score 0):

There is a route using [CSS3 Counters](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). I'm not familiar with the Kendo Editor, so be sure to add any other elements besides the `p` and `ul > li` base child elements in the CSS.

You can save the following CSS to be loaded within the editor:

```
body {
    counter-reset: editor;
    padding-left: 3em;
}
body > p,
body > ul > li {
    counter-increment: editor;
}
body > p:before,
body > ul > li:before {
    content: counter(editor);
    background: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 2em;
}
```

To add custom CSS within the editor, you would save the above into a file and in your initialization:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    stylesheets: ["path_to_your.css"]
});
```